# Linguagem Python 3.7.3 : FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] . .

Tags: python-3.x

Bom dia.

Tenho o seguinte code em uma classe que funciona perfeitamente bem quando printo dentro dela. Agora quando acesso por meio de um outro arquivo de classe me apresenta erro. Abaixo demonstro classe que funciona :

```
import os 
class WspApplication:

ws_listdir = os.listdir('../application/controllers')
```

Essa classe funciona quando dou o print dentro dela.

Ela somente apresenta o erro abaixo quando tento acessar ela em uma outra classe:

ws_listdir = os.listdir('../application/controllers')
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '../application/controllers'

Abaixo segue a outra classe :

```
from syscore.wsp_application import WspApplication
class WspProtected:

def wsm_dir(ws_path):

    ws_root = WspApplication.ws_listdir
    if ws_path == ws_root:
        return 'Info. . .'.encode('utf-8')
```

Pode desconsiderar o parâmetro path na analise ele funciona !

Comment: essas duas classes estão no mesmo diretório e/ou têm as mesmas permissões de acesso?

Comment: sim e estão sem permissões.

Comment: `../application/controllers` esse local está certo? ta na pasta do projeto?

Comment: Sim, as classe estão em um mesmo diretório já o path ( ../ application / controllers ) que estou querendo acessar estão em outro diretório conforme acima, mas na mesma raíz.